# Apache mod_pagespeed ignores redirected pages

Tags: apache, apache2

Using mod_pagespeed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) with an Apache Server, I noticed that some pages were not being processed. The pages in question all had one similar attribute - they were "redirected" pages - for example an ErrorDocument response or an "index.html" file serving as the response when a directory is requested.

Is there any way to remedy this? I've checked the FAQ and had a good trawl through the PageSpeed Documentation but to no avail.

Comment: How are you enabling which files get filtered through mod page speed?

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess with the mod_pagespeed configuration?